# how to select all items between two specific items based on id tags using xpath/scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have a following html:

```
<p id="d117" class="gen">Genre</p>
<a href='...'>Movie 1</a>
<a href='...'>Movie 2</a>
<p id="d127" class="gen">Genre</p>
<li>one</li>
<a href='...'>Movie 3</a>
<a href='...'>Movie 4</a>
<p id="d147" class="gen">Genre</p>
<li>two</li>
<a href='...'>Movie 5</a>
<a href='...'>Movie 6</a>
</root>
```

I want to select all the nodes after a certain-(p) id number until the next occurrence of the new id, I tried with the following XPath:

1. //p[@id="d147"]/preceding-sibling::*
2. //p[@id="d147"]/following-sibling::*

the above -1,2 works fine

But the below syntax does not give me a desired result of getting the lements between two id(intervals)  :

//p[@id="d117"]/following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::p[@id="d127"]]

Please guide me- to get the data between two id's using xpath

Comment: Have you checked syntax? you missed a `[` after `p`

Comment: Can you please point out exactly where did I miss?  As the above 1,2 syntax works only the third one in combination  was not working .

Comment: `//p--->[<----[@id="d117"]/following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::p[@id="d127"]]`

Answer (score 0):

`//a[preceding-sibling::p[@id='d117'] and following-sibling::p[@id='d127']]`